# Error in running MATLAB exe file within another program shows attempts to execute script as a function

Tags: matlab, exe, invoke

I have an exe file created by deploytool of MATLAB. It is running successfully from command prompt or normally. But when I am trying to run it from another program, it is showing an error `attempts to execute script as a function`.

I am not passing any parameter in invocation of that exe file. When I closed the message window, another message window appeared - `Error in mclFreeStackTrace`. 
I tried to run exe from using Batch file and instead of exe file, I executed Batch file from another program in which I was running exe file.
What is the problem with exe file.
Please help.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: How do you call the script which is giving an error in the compiled code? Did you try [`run`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html)? Posting the relevant code which causes the error could be helpful...

Comment: I am trying to run from .net page code. If I use batch file containing only Demo.exe file, then its working fine.